# Set Buttons' Background randomly from array of images

Tags: iphone

```
else if (setIndexPath == 4)
{
    viewWithButtons.frame = CGRectMake(5, 40, 310, 390);

    int ch = 6;
    int cv = 6;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < cv ; ++i )
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < ch ; ++j )
        {
            btnMatrix = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10+pw*j, 51+ph*i, width, height)] autorelease];
            btnMatrix.tag = i*ch+j;
            btnMatrix.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
            [btnMatrix addTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [btnMatrix setBackgroundImage:imgDefaultBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [viewWithButtons addSubview:btnMatrix];

            [arrButton addObject:btnMatrix];
        }
    }
}
[self.view addSubview:viewWithButtons];
```

I am generating buttons dynamically according to the selected matrix, like 4 * 4, 4 * 5, 4 * 6, 5 * 6, 6 * 6 etc....

Buttons are completely set as per the selected matrix from above (the code is for 6 * 6 matrix).

Now i have to set random background images of these buttons.

I am not able to set this kind of dynamic buttons' background.

is there any effective way to set backgrounds dynamically in random order for each separate buttons?

```
    for (intimg = 1; intimg <= 15; intimg++)
    {
        arr_FirstSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_f_2.png",intimg], nil];
    }
    for (intimgSET2 = 1; intimgSET2 <= 15; intimgSET2++) {
        arr_SecondSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_s_2.png",intimgSET2], nil];
    }
```

I am adding images in this format to the NSMutableArray.

How to pick random image from the above used arrays. I have to match both arrays images & give the result on buttons. If both matches, suppose i press on one button it will display 1_f_2.png  & on another button press it will display 1_s_2.png (as background)then both of these buttons will be removed from the view.

I had tried many logics to get this.

I am not getting exactly what i am interested to do on touchdown of button.

Please suggest any code snippet or link or code also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UIImage*)randomImage {
    NSInteger imageCount = [[self imageArray] count]
    return [[self imageArray] objectAtIndex:arc4random() % imageCount]; 
}
```

If you want matching pairs. Use dictionary with two images, or simple class holding two images.

Comment: it is being crashed...
arr_FirstSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_f_2.png",intimg], nil];
[self randomImage:intimg];


- (UIImage*)randomImage:(NSInteger)intgereValue
{
    NSInteger imageCount = intgereValue;
    return [arr_FirstSet objectAtIndex:arc4random() % imageCount]; 
}

Comment: Your arr_FirstSet is an array of strings and not UIImage objects.

Comment: - (NSString*)randomImageName { 
    NSInteger imageCount = [arr_FirstSet count]; 
    return [arr_FirstSet objectAtIndex:arc4random() % imageCount]; 
}

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self randomImageName];
[myButton setImage:image forState....];

Comment: Images are now set in the random order..... but the problem is that all these random images are changed on single button......instead being set to the separate buttons......once the background is set to the button this should not change on next click on it......on the basis of this, i have to check the pair & then i have to remove both the buttons from the game.....so once the background is set it must not change.